# Allure empty when run in jar

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit5, allure

I upgraded my project from JUnit4 to Junit5 and I'm trying to generate allure reports when I run my tests using a jar file but currently all I'm getting is **NaN%**, however I'm able to see all the attachments because I'm including aspectjweaver.  I know the listener is more than likely missing but I don't know how to add this in JUnit5.

My setup is Selenium+Gradle+Junit5, I'm also including TestMain to run my jar file.  Below I've added sample code to show difference between what I had in JUnit4 and what I currently have in JUnit5.

**JUnit4**

```
JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
    runner.addListener(new ExecutionListener());
    runner.addListener(new AllureJunit4());
    Result result = runner.run(testClass);
```

**JUnit5**

```
final LauncherDiscoveryRequest request =
        LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .selectors(selectClass(testclass))
            .build();

    final Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
    final SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();

    launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
    launcher.execute(request);
```

I've tried to register **new AllureJUnit5()** as a listener but obviously this doesn't work.

Blockquote